# Missing parameter type for 'value' | error in from Json method

Tags: dart

I have a from json method in my class but i'm getting an error in this part of the method:

```dart
timeToSpendEachDay:
          (map['timeToSpendEachDay'] as Map<String, dynamic>).map<Days, Time>(
        (key, value) =>
            MapEntry<Days, Time>(_stringToDay(key), Time(value as int)),
      ),
```

There is a red line under the first `value` saying `Missing parameter type for 'value'.`

this can be fixed by changing `dynamic` to `int` but when i do that another error comes when i run the script saying:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, int>' in type cast
```

So how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language does not require a type at that point, so what you see must be a result of extra enabled lints or analyzer options. Since the type of `value` is `dynamic`, it's probably "strict-inference" being set to true in your `analysis_options.yaml` file, or the `--no-implicit-dynamic` command line flag.

I'd change the parameter to `, dynamic value` to make the dynamic type *explicit* (and therefore not inferred). Alternatively, make it `, Object? value`, since all you do is `as int` on it anyway, you don't *use* the `dynamic` type for anything.